# "Your 1 hour 6 minutes are up" / "Your 1 hour 6 minutes is up"

Tags: grammatical-number, time

I'm not sure which of these is more correct.

> Your 1 hour is up.

This is easy. Singular.

> Your 5 minutes are up

Again, simple enough. Plural.

> Your 1 hour and 6 minutes is up.
>   Your 3 hours and 1 minute are up.

Should the plural be based on the hours or minutes?

Comment: “Your 66 minutes are up”? Or “Your allotted time slot of 1 hour and 6 minutes is up”? The simple fact that both the singular and the plural in your example sounds equally right and wrong is a good indication that avoiding the entire construction would be a prudent strategy.

Comment: "Your time is up."

Comment: Thanks Susan. In the context, I need to state the amount of time.

Comment: Your last 3 examples can use either singular or plural verb. It depends on notional concord. The issue involves *measure phrases* and *singular override*. For a more detailed answer, please refer to my "answer post".

Comment: I disagree with the "duplicate" closevote. That question will never address the issue in this one, which is the pluralization of complex measurements.

Comment: @MetaEd 'The the [time etc] interval is regarded as a unitary whole' (owtte) explanation given there covers this.

Answer (score 5):

According to Mary Nell Sorensen, instructor for the University of Washington International and English Language Programs, a set of rules on agreement are set out nicely [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/agreement.html). (And for a wider range of helpful charts, look [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/marynell).)

According to this chart, there are two rules that are applicable. The first one is specific:

> **Plural unit words of distance, money, and time. take a singular verb**
>
> > Examples:
>
> 300 miles is a long ways to go on a bicycle. (distance)
>
> Two hundred dollars seems a lot to spend on a dress. (money)
>
> Fifteen years is a long time to spend in jail. (time)

And a more general rule for compound subjects would be this:

> Subjects joined by and are nearly always plural
>
> **Exception: If the parts of the subject are considered a unit, you may treat the subject as singular.**

Thus, for your compound subject of a unit of time (X hours and Y minutes), it should be considered to be singular.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific examples -- except for the 1st one -- both the singular and the plural verb versions are acceptable. It depends on the speaker's/writer's intent.

When the subject is a type of measure phrase (which your examples are), then a *singular override* is usually **optional**.

Often the verb will be singular, since subjects that are a type of measure phrase are often treated as notionally singular by the speaker/writer. But the verb can be plural if the subject measure phrase is being treated notionally plural.

But, when a measure phrase is subject, be aware that the singular override is **obligatory** when the predicative complement is a singular noun phrase. E.g. *"Twenty dollars seems a ridiculous amount to pay to go to the movies"*.

Reference: page 504, "Measure phrases", in the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.

ASIDE: There's nothing wrong with the constructions of your examples, so use them if you like them. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the above example : 'Your one hour and six minutes' is taken as a time span, so it should be treated as a singular.

If it is taken in plural sense it should be formed like 'your 66 minutes are up'(minutes are countable).

Comment: Can you think of a situation where it makes sense to treat the minutes as discrete?

Comment: example: Minimum six minutes are required to complete the lap.

Comment: Few would treat that as discrete. You can have a minimum pressure, length, temperature which aren't – 'minimun' doesn't pre-modify solely count nouns. There is the situation, admittedly, where you are given a minute to collect as much litter as you can say, then must go and weigh it. (Winner gets a gold star!) If you have 6 'goes', you might well be told 'Six minutes are what each pupil gets.'

Answer (score 0):

it makes a prudent choice to consider the subject as singular.
E.g. Ten Pounds is heavier than you think/your 1 hour 6 minutes is up
Reference:
http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/category/singular-vs-plural/

Answer (score -4):

"If the subject includes singular and plural items, the verb agrees with the item closest to the verb."

Correct answer: Your 1 hour 6 minutes ***are*** up.

http://faculty.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/agreement.html

Comment: Exception: If the parts of the subject are considered a unit, you may treat the subject as singular. -- 'Your time is up.' = 'Your one hour and three minutes is up.' would you like to change your choice to door number 2 or door number 3?

Comment: Your cite actually says the opposite: plural amounts of time take the singular: *Fifteen years is a long time to spend in jail. (time)*. Also the same cite says if a plural or compound forms a unit, it takes the singular: *Crackers and cheese is my favorite snack*.

Comment: @Drew - welcome to ELU. You made a good effort by aanswering with a citation of an authoritative reference. But your answer conflicts with your source. Fix your answer, and the downvotes should be retracted.

Comment: @Jim - Fix your comment and I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @bib *Fifteen years is a long time* in this instance, the singular  relates to the *period* of fifteen years. One must imagine that the full sentence is ***a period of*** *fifteen years is a long time*. Consider the sentence *Fifteen years have passed since then*. No-one would every try to pass off *Fifteen years has passed* as correct, but that would be using the singular.

Comment: @roryok Your [period of] 1 hour 6 minutes *is* up. I have no problem with *Fifteen years has passed ...*.

Comment: *Fifteen years has passed...*  Now that I read it back again it doesn't seem so bad. Still no closer to a definitive answer.

Comment: @Jim The classic Monty Hall problem?

Comment: His odds would have been better if he had accepted my offer, don't you think? Some people are stubborn, though. They usually go home with the goat.

Comment: I knew a gal went home with Monty Hall.