# Should we use IS or Are with 'Fifty meters (is, are) the length of this pool.' etc?

Tags: grammar

Fifty meters (is, are) the length of this pool.

Ten dollars (is, are) too much to pay for a book.

One sixth of the cake (was, were) eaten.

One half of the students (is, are) going.

Kindly help me to answer those questions please..

Comment: Also see *[“Your 1 hour 6 minutes are up” / “Your 1 hour 6 minutes is up”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151819)* ; *[Plural/singular verb agreement with units](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155)*, *[Does modifying a collective noun with a number make the subject plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79728)* and many others.

Answer (score -2):

Fifty meters is the length of this pool.

Ten dollars is too much to pay for a book.

One sixth of the cake was eaten.

One half of the students are going.

(this one is different because one half of a group of things is still a plural)

Kindly help me to answer those questions please..

Comment: Hello, John. This has been covered before.